# Connect SQL Server and Display data in Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, web-part, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get data from SQL SERVER and  display in SharePoint 2013 web part. I wrote following code to connect SQL SERVER. But it gives an error "login failed for user 'nt authority iusr" when connecting. But same code work for C#.
  Is the issue is something related to SharePoint?

```
 string connetionString = "Data Source=WIN-SERVER2012;Initial Catalog=ExternalDBTest;User ID=Administrator; Password=password; Trusted_Connection=True";
 using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
            {
                  cn.Open();

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `Trusted_Connection=True` from your connection string when you try to use `SQL Authentication`.

`Trusted_Connection=True` is only used with `Windows Authentication` and in your case, this user `User ID=Administrator` will be ignored , so the connection string tries to connect to your database with this user `nt authority iusr` that does not have access to `ExternalDBTest`

Comment: It's not working for me. I get an error login failed for the user.

Comment: Make sure that the provided user has elevated privileges to your database and also don't add Trusted_Connection=True, or try to use sa user and check , I am pretty sure the issue related Trusted_Connection=True and current user permission or password